# What is wrong with my probability formula?

Tags: probability, statistics

[image]

My thought process was this, if they attack they have a 25% chance of getting 3 points, 25% chance of getting 1 point and 50% chance of getting 0 points

Now on the other hand if they go defensive, theres a 15% chance of them getting 3 points, 50% chance of them getting 1 point and 35% chance of them getting 0 points.

This seems obvious to me that the obvious route would be defensive, yielding more points with a lower probability of actually loosing, which gets you 0 points. it simply asks for the higher number of expected points, so I would go defensive. If I am wrong, please correct me, thank you in advance!

Comment: You can use the multinomial distribution to calculate the number expected points for n games: $E(A)=n$, $E(D)=0.95n$. So you are not right.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of [expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value)?

Comment: The math in the comment of @callculus being dead on accurate, you can **simulate** the computations by pretending that the two opponents will play **exactly 100 games** against each other, instead of only 1 game.  Then, which strategy works out best after 100 games?  Here, I am making the natural assumption (for example) that if a particular strategy has a $15$% chance of a win, then the team will win exactly 15 games out of the 100 played.

Comment: The thing that is wrong with your probability formula is that you don't appear to have one. You haven't shown how going defensive would yield more points, or how many points it would yield.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you calculate the [expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) of each strategy, you can see which one will, on average, win out over a long series of games.

The expected value of a random variable $X$ is defined as $E[X] = \sum_i {x_i*P[X=x_i]}$. Essentially, this is the weighted average over all possible outcomes, weighted by the probabilities.

In this case, the expected value of any strategy is:

$$ E[\text{Strategy}] = 3*P[\text{Win}]+1*P[\text{Draw}]+0*P[\text{Loss}]$$

If the strategy is "attacking," then we have

$$ E[\text{Attack}] = 3*0.25 + 1*0.25 + 0*0.50 = 1 . $$

Similarly, if the strategy is "defensive," then we have

$$ E[\text{Defense}] = 3*0.15 + 1*0.50 + 0*0.35 = 0.95 . $$

So, it looks like attacking is a slightly better strategy.

Of course, this is not meant to explain what happens in any *one* match, but what would happen on average if you were able to play the same match several times under the exact same conditions.

You could expect to win, on average, 1 point per match if you employed only the attacking strategy, and 0.95 points per match if you employed only the defensive strategy.